# Memory keep unreleased with more than one CDHtmlDialogs.(navigate same Url)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

MFC create Modaless CDHtmlDialog more than one time and delete one or more, Memory keep unreleased and heaped up 10~20MB per one CDHtmlDialog until create new modaless CDHtmlDialog with all CDHtmlDialog deleted.

I tried these solution. But Not solved.

```
    VOID CMyManagerDlg::CreateMyDlg()
    {
        CMyDlg *pMyDlg = new CMyDlg();
        pMyDlg->Create(IDD_CID, GetDesktopWindow());
        m_pMyDlg = pMyDlg;
        m_pMyDlg->Navigate("https://www.googole.com");
        m_pMyDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    }          
    VOID CMyManagerDlg::RemoveMyDlg()
    {
        m_pMyDlg->DestroyModeless();
        CoFreeUnusedLibraries();  // sol1
    }   
    void CMyDlg::PostNcDestroy()
    {
        delete this;   //sol2
        CDHtmlDialog::PostNcDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: What is `DestroyModeless`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdhtmldialog-class?view=vs-2017#destroymodeless

Comment: The CWnd::DestroyWindow member function must be used to destroy modeless dialog boxes that are created by CDialog::Create. Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdhtmldialog-class?view=vs-2017#_dtorcdhtmldialog).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT So What??? I DID Create Dialog. " pMyDlg->Create(IDD_CID, GetDesktopWindow());" Can't you see tht?? My question is about memory problem not such kind of that.

Comment: So have you called DestroyWindow when you want to destroy modeless dialog box?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT yeah. Same result.